# Unable to extract Zip file using unzip step in kettle

Tags: kettle

I am tring to extract an 2gb file using pantaho kittle unzip step . But I am getting below error.

Unzip file - ERROR (version 4.3.0-stable, build 16786 from 2012-04-24 14.11.32 by buildguy) : Error

Can any one help me in doing so.

Thanks

Comment: There should me more to the error than that, check the log or on the console and post the full error.  Also whats in the file?  do you definitely need to unzip it?  (i.e. pdi can read compressed text/csv files directly without unzipping)

Comment: Actully as the size of the file is 2gb that's why it is unable to process such a large file. I guess it is an bug in kettle .

Comment: hmm ok. How about if you just use a shell command to unzip the file?  Actually thinking about it, are zip files even valid of that size?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you did not set the target directory in the unzip step: 
"Unzipped files" / "Target Directory"